# db cursor - transaction in python

Tags: python, database, transactions, cursor

Is opening/closing db cursor costly operation? What is the best practice, to use a different cursor or to reuse the same cursor between different sql executions? Does it matter if a transaction consists of executions performed on same or different cursors belonging to same connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend a lot on your database as well as your chose python implementation - have you tried profiling a few short test operations?

Comment: No I didnt do any testing yet. I was thinking this is a conceptual issue more than implementation issue. and I am using mysql 5.1 with python 2.6 on linux using mysqldb and/or oursql bindings.

Comment: It looks like creating a cursor has _more_ of a cost than reusing a cursor, but not noticably much unless you are using it an awful number of times. It really depends on your implementation whether it's worth doing - it may look cleaner to create a new cursor each time, and it really depends on whether this operation is on your critical path. Ask yourself how much time this will save, the effect that will have on user perception, and the effect putting that effort into other parts of your program.

Comment: Then it is ok for me to reuse it. Cursors has no direct relationship with transactions right ? I can commit/rollback executions of different cursors ?

Comment: I'm not sure about rollback etc as I personally haven't used it, and I'm not sure if I fully understand that part of your question, however I beleive a cursor is more like a placeholder - think of it like a bookmark - you can reuse a bookmark but you'll lose your place in the book you took it from, or you can get a new one, but then you have to go to the shops or make your own from a scrap of paper, both cost more than reuse but they give you an advantage that you don't have to find your place again :P